# Paypal .Net SDK and Recurring Profiles

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a number of Paypal recurring payments.  I am just upgrading to the Paypal .net REST API SDK and I cannot retrieve any information about these recurring payments.

```
        var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
        Console.WriteLine(Plan.Get(apiContext, "I-S999X9XXXXXX").create_time.ToString());
        var planList = Plan.List(apiContext);
```

I receive a 404 error suggesting that the ID has not been found.

Are "recurring payments" the same thing as "Billing Plans" ?  Or are they different. The samples seem to have a different format ID than I have.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create billing plans; that is, planned sets of future
>   recurring payments at periodic intervals (sometimes known as
>   "subscriptions"). First define a billing plan that specifies the
>   number of payments, their frequency, and other payment details using
>   the /billing-plans resource. Activate it so that the billing agreement
>   can be created.

The Plan.List method just returns the list of created plans (status == 'CREATED'). You have to pass the status ACTIVE if you can see the active ones.

```
var planList = Plan.List(apiContext: apiContext, status: "ACTIVE");
```

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/paypal-integration-part-2-paypal-rest-api--cms-22917) you find a good tutorial that covers the Billing Plan Creation and the Billing Agreement creation and execution processes.